# multiple cameras for simple RPG game

Tags: game-engine, camera, logic-bricks

I am developing a simple rpg steampunk game. Can anyone tell me how do I make, with logic bricks, a simple key (for example <kbd>C</kbd>) switch to a second camera view? I have 2 cameras placed in different angles in the scene. I can not program python. If it is of course possible only using logic bricks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *Scene* -> *Set Camera* Brick.

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard Sensor -> AND/OR/... -> Scene Actuator in Set Camera mode.

[image]

Comment: This answers how to change the scene, not the scene's camera

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned the wrong mode. It should be the set camera mode indeed.